# Service workers - always serve from network and cache resource

Tags: service-worker, offline-caching

Struggling with this a bit, so any help would be appreciated.

We run websites which are constantly updated with a CMS, but want to cache the page for offline/slow use.

We are at a bit of a loss of how to serve the resource from the network, but also cache it (or update the cached version) when doing so.

This is our code so far but all it seems to do is load the CSS, JS and other pages from the cache.

Any suggestions very much appreciated.

```
event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request)
        .then(response => {
            // Loads from network
            debug(`Loading from network: ${response.url}`);

            caches.open(config.cayg.key + config.version)
                .then(cache => {
                    cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                });

            return response;
        })
        .catch(response => {
            // try cache
            debug(`Loading from cache: ${response.url}`);
            caches.match(event.request)
                .then(response)
                .catch(() => caches.match('/offline/')); // otherwise show offline
        })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla encapsulates most of the use cases and provides examples and descriptions for the different recipes/strategies.  Try the "network or cache" strategy:

https://serviceworke.rs/strategy-network-or-cache.html

(UI is a little non-intuitive and demo/code links are on top of page)